# Imagemagic and php exec: convert: no images defined

Tags: php, imagemagick

The command works just fine from the shell

```
/opt/ImageMagick/bin/convert /private/var/folders/nl/9cky1krj5_j7zwm34tfkndd40000gn/T/pdfPyflQF /private/var/folders/nl/9cky1krj5_j7zwm34tfkndd40000gn/T/imgRilIdW 2>&1
```

I got image generated. But if I run it with `php` `exec` function I get error

```
Array
(
    [0] => convert: no images defined `/private/var/folders/nl/9cky1krj5_j7zwm34tfkndd40000gn/T/imgRilIdW' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.
)
```

Seems it's not permission issue. File permissions are 666. Can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: check the path context. php and/or imagemagik may be interpreting the from root, from imagemagik's location, from the script location, etc.

Comment: @Yorik But pathes are absolute. How other they can be interpreting?

Comment: maybe thats the problem. check the context: where is the script calling from, php access those folders, etc.

Comment: Did you figure it out?